backend dependency within Svelte component library gets imported on SvelteKit (Vite/Rollup) build
I created a Svelte component library which uses better-sqlite3 for some backend methods.
When building an app which uses this custom library, better-sqlite3 gets imported and bundled, causing issues with underlying dependencies like bindings which use commonJS.
This issue doesn't occur when better-sqlite3 is in the package.json of the app. Then all better-sqlite3 import statements are not imported/bundled and remain as-is; linked to node_modules.

How to force Vite not to bundle backend dependencies from my library without having them in the apps package.json (offcourse they are mentioned in the libraries package.json!)
What's best practice regarding these backend dependencies? Is there a way to get them in the build without them being optimized/imported?


In the Vite config, there are dependency optimization options, you might be looking for optimizeDeps.exclude.
